# How to transform a String to a Date JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, parsing, format, transform

I have the following line

```
<Date Format="YYYYMMDD">20190304</Date>
```

And I need to get a date from this format `20190304`. 
So I have this code to accomplish my goal:

```
var str = '20190304';
var date = Date.parse(str.substring(0,4) + '-' + str.substring(4,6) + '-' + str.substring(6,8));
var date2 = new Date(date)
console.log(date2);
```

Result :

```
Mon Mar 04 2019 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)
```

The problem is, this code will only work, if the format matches exactly `YYYYMMDD`.
Unfortunatley, I need to find a method which works with every format specified.

Comment: You can't make code that will work for any format. If I invent a new format that says that `qsdf` equals `04/03/2019` will not be able to parse that.

Comment: There are many possible date formats. You will have to write code for each of them and test it until one works. Or you could try and attempt to create a Date object directly; if it fails then you have at least reduced the possible number of alternative date formats to check.

Comment: Even then, you would not be able to distinguish between month or day (mm-dd) or (dd-mm) reliably.

Comment: If you're ok using moment.js, you can have a list of possible formats at least. See a sample implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384176/4636715

Comment: use moment.js where you can define the format and then create the dates
https://flaviocopes.com/momentjs/

Comment: You should use moment.js if possible

Comment: Which exact date formats you need to transform? What are the possible inputs?

Comment: I don't know the input format until i parse it

Comment: from where you are getting these dates? it cant be in random format on each hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use momentjs for your requirement

```js
var date = moment('20190312', 'YYYYMMDD', true);

console.log(date.format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You still need to specify the format the input string is in

Comment: The OP doesn't know the format of the timestamp, so a library isn't going to help.